# UILabel with horizontal padding?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, uiview, uilabel

I'm new to ios development and i'm struggling to make something that should be trivial.

I want simple container with background color and single line text inside with padding and i prefer to make it programmatically (no IB).

What i've already tried:

- simple `UILabel` vertical padding is not a problem with fixed height but no horizontal;
- also `UIView` with `UILabel` as subview - adding background color to `UIView` and the label is just text `sizeToFit`;

When i am using `UIView` with `UILabel` as subview i've set:
`[self.myTestView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];`

but because i'am using `NSLayoutConstraint` when i set `self.myTestView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;` i don't have proper autoresizing.

If it helps i'am trying this into `UICollectionViewCell`?

Just for additional information i know this can be achieved with `UIButton` and using `UIEdgeInsets`, but i don't want to use `UIButton` for simple text container.

Does anybody have an idea or direction?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Why you just didn't add constraint to your label inside uiview in IB, with padding what you need?!
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qTGt.png

Comment: sorry i forgot to tell in the question i prefer to make it programmatically.